# registerForActivityResult doesn't return expected values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've made an registerForActivityResult, to let user enable the Location service, after it'll get enabled, I'd like to perform future actions. My struggle is that, there's no difference if I will enable Location service or not. the output is the same:

```
TEST: ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}
```

How I can get proper data (whenever the Location was enabled, or not)?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private val openLocationSettings =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            Log.i(TAG, "TEST: $result")
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val locationManager =
                    this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Title")
                    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Message")
                    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Enable") { dialog, which ->

                        openLocationSettings.launch(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case where settings intent is used, startactivityforresult does not make any difference. You have check again in closure if location services was enabled. You will also have to get runtime location permissions. You could also use google play services dependency which allows to turn on location services without going to settings but only works for 31+

Comment: What makes you think that `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` returns any result? It is [specifically documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS) as not outputting anything.